# Remove the legend on chartscrollbar on amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

So in the picture attached I would like to remove the data in the scrollbar itself. I've poked around in the chart as much as possible. Best I was able to find was to straight up remove all the labels which is not what I want to do. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels in the `valueScrollbar` are a result of setting [`autoGridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartScrollbar#autoGridCount) to true. You either have to remove the `autoGridCount` setting or set it to false to remove the labels in the scrollbar.